# Determine whether this statement is true or false $\forall x \in {Z}, \exists y , z \in {Z} [x = 5y + 7z] $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Just beginning in Discrete math stumbled into the symbolic logic section and need some selp on this question, any input is appreciated.

$$ \forall x \in {Z}, \exists y , z \in {Z}  [x = 5y + 7z] $$

Determine whether this statement is true or false.

Comment: Your opinion ? True or False ?

Comment: Hint: $5(-4)+7(3)=1$.

Comment: My intuition says that its false because y isn't bound to any kind of domain and this kind of equation generally only works nice on the integers, but thats just off the cuff, the real problem I think i'm having is not knowing quite how/where to approach proving/disproving falsity/truth.

Comment: @J2R5M3, the usual convention is to interpret "$\exists y,z\in Z$" as meaning that *both* $y$ and $z$ are in $Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\gcd(5,7) = 1$, there exist $m,n$ such that $5m+7n = 1$. And every integer can be written as a sum of $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: $ 0 = 1 + (-1) $

Comment: @Zack Ni ... Thus the answer "it's true" has won by 1 to 0...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes it is true.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true.

---

Given $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, choose:

- $y=\color\red{+3x}\in\mathbb{Z}$
- $z=\color\green{-2x}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Then $x=15x-14x=5\cdot(\color\red{+3x})+7\cdot(\color\green{-2x})=5y+7z$.

Comment: This answer has the advantage of not requiring induction. Of course, the disadvantage is that one has to come up with those 'magical' constants for each such theorem. Note to other readers: those constants can be systematically found by the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example:

$$760 = 5\cdot 12 + 7 \cdot 100$$

For this, $760$ has a solution $(12, 100)$.  Can you find a solution for $765$ ? What about $770$ ? What about $755$?  What about a general $760 + 5k$ ?

If, knowing how to find a solution for $x$, you also can find a solution for $x \pm 5$, then it suffices to find a solution for the 5 cases : $x = 0, x = 1, x = 2, x = 3$, and $x = 4$.